# LocationManager will not return destination

Tags: android

I created this earlier on today, but it is not working. Location manager returns null, and I've even implemented the listener. Any ideas to the problems. thanks.

Edited:
I think this line is the problem

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Basically, if location is null, it will go into the else part of the if statement below it. Every time I compile the code, it will go into the else statement meaning it location is not updating.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
JoshTwoActivity main;
Activity2 two;
boolean checkTick = false;
String locationplace = "";
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


               locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    System.out.println(provider);
    System.out.println(locationManager.getProviders(criteria, false));
    System.out.println(locationManager.getProvider("network"));
    System.out.println(locationManager.getAllProviders());

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    System.out.println(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider));

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(lat));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(lng));

    } else {
        System.out.println("Provider not available");
        System.out.println("Provider not available");
    }

}


/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(lat));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disenabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: what is the provider that you are using?

Comment: provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

This has been returning network if that is what you are saying

Comment: are you testing on emulator ?

Comment: is your device wifi enabled? and what do you mean by locationManager returning null?, can you give more details by editing your post?

Comment: I am using an emulator. I'll edit the comments in my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my first guess is that you are not giving location fix via command line or by using eclipse DDMS perpective. If this is problem go open DDMS perpecive and give latitude and longtiude you want and send it. So location will not be null from now on if this is the problem.

Comment: problem is though, when I want to publish the application I won't be able to use the DDMS. I put it in as you said and still got null though.

Comment: of course you dont have DDMS on actual device, DDMS is there to simulate that process. As I said before you are probably not giving location fix cause when emulator fires up there is no location info attached to it by doing that process via DDMS you can get last know location so your location object shouldnt be null.

Comment: Right o. I shall attempt that now.

Answer (score 1):

getLastKnownLocation() returns a location with the last known location fix for a provider.  If the provider returns null, the provider has never had a location fix.  It doesn't mean the provider is not available.

Once you call getLastKnownLocation() you should check to see if the results are accurate or recent enough for your purpose.  If not you should request location updates using requestLocationUpdates().

This blog post contains everything you need to know about writing code using location providers.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Answer (score 0):

The following link may help you in understanding how to use emulator in finding the location. The last section of this page has that information.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html